# my device doesn't switch on it keeps restarting is there anyway i can get my contacts numbers

Tags: contacts, lost-phone, copy-paste

My samsung note 4 edge doesn't open after a software problem it keeps restarting every time it opens and it doesn't take even 5 seconds then it goes of , is there anyway i can get my contacts numbers although they are still in the device but cant copy them since it auto restart every time i switch on and i dont have a backup :'( , thank you in advance ..

Comment: Where/when does it restart? Be specific.

Comment: Tried booting into Safe mode?

Comment: @AaronGillion as soon as it goes on 5 seconds after showing the wallpaper it goes off and restart .

Comment: @Manubhargav i did try and still ..

Answer (score 0):

That 5 seconds can be a life changer. That should be just enough to copy a few files at a time over plain USB connection. You'd really have about 15 seconds as MTP is initiated mid-way through the boot animation.

That will get your photos, but not the app data from contacts. Those should be synced with your Google acoount, even if you turned off "backup my data to Google" in "Backup and Reset", but you have sync turned on with a checkmark next to "Contacts".

If that doesn't help, try to use that 5 seconds to enable USB debugging from settings, and launch an `adb backup -system -noapk` via ADB from mid-way past the boot animation when USB is recognized. You may also be able to use adb from recovery mode, which will give you enough time for a complete backup.

This is all assuming you have a locked bootloader. If you're on T-mobile or international edition, your bootloader is unlocked. You can easily recover data after flashing TWRP, CWM, or Philz Touch via Odin.

Comment: That `adb backup` would never be able to achieve success since: 1) contacts are never backed up by ADB unless Samsung deliberately messed up, 2) all system apps can't be backed up in five seconds. Once the device reboots the connection would end and the partial backup would be of no use. Since the whole cycle would have to repeated, it would only cause headache. 3) Stock recoveries (at least `<3e>`) doesn't offer shell access let alone root access so contacts and photos still can't be backed up using a stock recovery.

Comment: MTP wouldn't help as well. MTP is slow to process, everyone knows. Once the device reboots and under five seconds you select MTP as USB connection mode, you'd still have to browse the files in PC needed to be  copied from phone. The time is too small to do anything useful. // That method about sync is a trial and error. It doesn't guarantee that it would work. Provide us a method that gives the user a good clue *that contacts were indeed synced in five seconds*.

Comment: // Since the rest of the methods are not useful or good, consider telling us how to flash at least one of the custom recovery and then how to use it for the desired goal.  Thanks!